# Limit Unknown excel range and stop IEnumerable function

Tags: c#, generics, office-interop, excel-interop

I am working on an Excel based C# project where I have to put a whole column of data into a single dimensional array but I am unable to find proper way to do so.

The code I have used is although working but it drops the whole data of a column including unused cells (after the used range of my Excel column) into an array which wastes system resources.

The other problem is the built-in select function of `IEnumerable` class; I don't know how to stop it when it encounters null value.

```
Excel.Range range3 = sheet.get_Range("A:A");

string[] strArray = range3.Cells.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(Selector).ToArray<string>();

public string Selector(Excel.Range cell)
{
    if (cell.Value2 == null)
        return null ; // what to return and how to stop this function 

    if (cell.Value2.GetType().ToString() == "System.Double")
        return ((double)cell.Value2).ToString();
    else if (cell.Value2.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
        return ((string)cell.Value2);
    else if (cell.Value2.GetType().ToString() == "System.Boolean")
        return ((bool)cell.Value2).ToString();
    else
        return "unknown";
}
```

Comment: I'd note that your `Selector` method doesn't really do much, you're still calling `ToString` on all known types. Replacing the whole thing with `return cell.Value2?.ToString()` would achieve much the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TakeWhile LINQ extension method:

```cs
 string[] strArray = range3.Cells.Cast<Excel.Range>()
    .Select(Selector)
    .TakeWhile(s => s != null)
    .ToArray();
```

As @CharlesMager suggests, you could replace the Selector function by

```cs
    .Select(c => c.Value2 is dynamic[] ? "unknown" : c.Value2?.ToString())
```

According to your comment, the cell value can be an array of `dynamic` which cannot be converted to string. We return "unknown" in this case in a [ternary expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

In your Selector function you are doing things like

```
if (cell.Value2.GetType().ToString() == "System.Double")
    return ((double)cell.Value2).ToString();
```

In C# you can test a type with

```cs
if (cell.Value2 is double)
```

However, this is not necessary, as you can convert a value to string without knowing its type:

```
    return cell.Value2.ToString();
```

And, btw., if you know that it is a double, you don't need to cast it to double.

The problem here is that `Value2` can be null. Calling `ToString` will throw a null reference exception in this case. To avoid this, you can use the null-conditional operator `?`:

```cs
    return cell.Value2?.ToString();
```

This will call `ToString` only if the value is not null.

Comment: After using your code , should I delete the Selector function

Comment: After replacing the code , it is giving me the error                                                              string[] strArray = range3.Cells.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(c => c.Value2?.ToString()).TakeWhile(s => s != null).ToArray();                   Cannot implicitly convert type 'dynamic[]' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)